# Replace initial NA values with zero in a row until non NA column

Tags: r, vector, na

Consider the following row in a dataset:-

```
#Row (initially):
NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 2 3 1 4 5 2 NA NA 6 7
```

I want all such rows to be transformed into

```
#Row  (modified) :
0  0  0  0  0  0  0 2 3 1 4 5 2 NA NA 6 7
```

Only the initial NA that occur before any non na value shout be replaced by zero and not those that come afterwards.

**Edit:** My data is matrix, example:

```
NA   NA   NA   NA    1    1    1    1    1     1
NA   NA   NA   NA    1    1    1    1    1     1
NA   NA   NA   NA    1    1    1    1    1     1
NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    1   NA     1
NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    1   NA     1
NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA     1
1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1   NA     1
1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
```

It should be modified to

```
0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1     1
0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1     1
0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1     1
0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1   NA     1
0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1   NA     1
0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1
1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1   NA     1
1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a function and use apply. Here a working example. The function is just testing if the cumsum of logic values is increasing.

```
x<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,1,0,NA,NA,3)
    y<-c(2,NA,3,NA,1,0,NA,2,3)
    z<-c(NA,NA,3,NA,1,0,NA,NA,3)
    df<-data.frame(x,y,z)


    initialNA<-function(x){
      index<-cumsum(is.na(x))>=seq_along(x)
      x[index]<-0
      x
    }

    df2<-data.frame(t(apply(df,1,initialNA)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with `rle()`:

```
x <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 2, NA, NA, 6, 7)
if (is.na(x[1])) x[1:rle(is.na(x))$lengths[1]] <- 0
x
```

For rowwise application:

```
f <- function(x) {
    if (is.na(x[1])) x[1:rle(is.na(x))$lengths[1]] <- 0
    x
}
apply(yourMatrix, 1, f)
```

Eventually you have to transpose the result because `apply()` constructs the result column by column from the rows of your matrix:

```
t(apply(yourMatrix, 1, f))
```

#### with package zoo:

There is a function in `zoo` for this task:

```
x <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 2, NA, NA, 6, 7)
library("zoo")
na.fill(x, c(0,NA,NA))
```

Answer (score 1):

For the updated example :

We can use `apply` row-wise and `replace` the values with 0 till the first occurrence of a non-NA value.

```
t(apply(mat, 1, function(x) replace(x, cumsum(!is.na(x)) == 0, 0)))


#     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
#[1,]  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1   1
#[2,]  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1   1
#[3,]  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1   1
#[4,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1 NA   1
#[5,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1 NA   1
#[6,]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   1
#[7,]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 NA   1
#[8,]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
```

**Original Answer**

We can use `which` and `min` together to find the index of first non-NA value and replace those values with 0.

```
x[1:min(which(!is.na(x))) - 1] <- 0
x
#[1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  3  1  4  5  2 NA NA  6  7
```

Or with `which.max`

```
x[1:which.max(!is.na(x)) - 1] <- 0
```

and the most simplest with `which.min`

```
x[1:which.min(is.na(x)) - 1] <- 0
```

**data**

```
x <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 2, NA, NA, 6, 7)
```

Comment: this will have to be performed row-wise on each row. Is it possible to do so for entire matrix.

Comment: @rishabh could you please update your question with an example explaining what you are trying to do?

Comment: The idea of your edit stems from my answer! I would not have done this.

Answer (score 1):

Using `cummin`:

```
x[cummin(is.na(x))==1] <- 0

#[1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  3  1  4  5  2 NA NA  6  7
```

`cumprod` can also be used.

As for your edit, to do the same for the whole matrix say `m`:

```
t(apply(m,1,function(x) replace(x, cummin(is.na(x))==1, 0)))

    # [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1     1
# [2,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1     1
# [3,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1     1
# [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1   NA     1
# [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1   NA     1
# [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1
# [7,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1   NA     1
# [8,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
```